# Windows 8.1 third party firewalls and Hyper-V virtual switch compatibility

Tags: networking, firewall, hyper-v

I have the following problem:

- Hyper-V is installed on windows 8.1 with an external virtual switch.
- Everything works fine with windows firewall
- When I try to install any third party firewall on windows 8.1, the ethernet card disappears (error in device management) and the vEthernet is disconnected.
- I tried to let windows solve the problem as well as reinstall the network card without success.

I can not find any posts about this. I tried fresh w8.1 installs and several firewalls, the problem is always the same.

Any expert answer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a fresh install with the firewall installed first, right after windows 8.1 installation. Hyper-V was then activated. It went like a charm...